# MS Excel - Unique name within the same column

Tags: duplicate, string

This may be an already asked question, but unable to locate a solution that is suiting my needs...
I have an Excel sheet of >24K entries. The Problem I have is the entries in a particular column are duplicated. e.g. it might be ABCD (or) ABCD12 (or) ABCD12.xxx. What will be in common will be the first 4 characters. I will also have a unique serial number to each of the rows.
     Will it be possible to highlight those repeats with the matching serial number against the duplicate cell? This will help me in locating the duplicates and decide to delete it off?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

First create a column with this formula and I think you have your answer.

**=Left(reference cell, 4)**

Use the newly created column to sort same type entry. Hope this helps.